# Split id and add to array

Tags: java

I have to split off the last two characters of an ID, the id may vary in length. example 56427R1 and R00220P3. Once the last two characters are split off, I need to add the first set of characters and the last two characters to an ArrayList. Thanks in advance.

I've tried the following

```
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add(clientValue.substring(0, clientValue.length()-2));
```

but was having trouble keeping the last 2 characters while removing the first half.

Resolved, repaired with the following code

```
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add(clientValue.substring(clientValue.length()-2));
            list.add(clientValue.substring(0, clientValue.length()-2));
```

Comment: Can you give example on what is the expected output for your example inputs?

Comment: I would like a coffee, please an espresso one, oh no, I haven't started preparing it yet. Seriously, try to show that you are at least trying solving your own problem.

Comment: As others have pointed out.  It's best to show you've done your due diligence before bringing questions here.  I suggest starting by looking at strings in java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: please see update, I forgot to past my code sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String.substring()` with `String.length()` to split the string.

Use `ArrayList<String>.add()` to append to an `ArrayList`.

EDIT:

the code you have posted is correct: `clientValue` is not modified by the call to `clientValue.substring()` but returns a new `String` instance. Java `String` are immutable.
To complete your code:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(clientValue.substring(0, clientValue.length()-2));
list.add(clientValue.substring(clientValue.length()-2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily like this:

```
String myID = "56427R1";
String extractedID = myID.substring((myID.length()-2), myID.length());
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>;v
list.add(myID.substring((myID.length()-2)));
list.add(extractedID);
```

UPDATE:

```
String myID = "56427R1";
String extractedID = myID.substring((myID.length()-2), myID.length());

char[] a = extractedID.toCharArray();
char[] b = myID.substring(myID.length()-2).toCharArray();
ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();

for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
list.add(b[i]);

for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
list.add(a[j]);
```

Comment: This code was only adding r1 to the list rather than the first set of digits with the r1.

Comment: lol I tried to help and you downvote. cool. do this: char[] a = id.toCharArray();
  ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
  for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
   list.add(a[i]);

Answer (score 0):

```
string tmp = "56427R1";

ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList()<String>;
arrayList.add(tmp.substring(tmp.length() - 2));
arrayList.add(tmp.substring((tmp.length() - 2), tmp.length()));
```

Comment: This code was only adding r1 to the list rather than the first set of digits with the r1.